# Direct2D vs GDI+ Without a Dedicated Graphics Card

Tags: c++, graphics, game-engine, gdi+, direct2d

I have been writing a billiards game in GDI+. I've sunk a ton of time into it, and my performance is poor. I average about 13 frames per second when I really want 50 - 60. I have started optimizing my code, but my biggest bottlenecks don't look like they can get much better. Just drawing and filling a few polygons is taking up to 20ms.

I've read that GDI+ does not work close to the hardware to gain performance, while Direct2D does. Since I don't have a dedicated graphics card, I'm not sure I would see any gain in performance if I were to rewrite the project in Direct2D instead. Is this true? I'd be willing to do it, but I don't want to spend hours rewriting it unless there's a very good chance the performance will be better.

**EDIT** This function is my biggest bottleneck. I used the std::clock to time out different segments of the function. I've marked different segments as comments.

On average, Segment 1 takes 9ms to draw, Segment 2 takes 8ms to draw, and segment 3 takes 1.5ms to draw. I would assume segment 1 takes a while because it's using TextureBrush which uses an Image. Segment 2 is a polygon with 25 vertices. I really don't know if I can cut that number down. Is there anything else I can do?

```
void CTable::Draw(Gdiplus::Graphics* graphics)
{
    // Segment 1
    graphics->FillRectangle(&woodBrush, mTLTable.X, mTLTable.Y, mLenTable, mWidTable);

    // Segment 2
    graphics->FillRectangle(&felt, mTLFelt.X, mTLFelt.Y, mFeltLen + 2 * mRailWid, mFeltWid + 2 * mRailWid);
    graphics->DrawPath(&feltBorder, &mFelt);

    // Segment 3
    graphics->FillPath(&pocketBrush, &mTLPocket);
    graphics->FillPath(&pocketBrush, &mBRPocket);
    graphics->FillPath(&pocketBrush, &mTRPocket);
    graphics->FillPath(&pocketBrush, &mBLPocket);
    graphics->FillPath(&pocketBrush, &mTMPocket);
    graphics->FillPath(&pocketBrush, &mBMPocket);
}
```

Here is how my graphics object is created. The graphics object is passed to the OnDraw function, which will call a Draw function (that takes the graphics object as an argument) on each game object.

```
void CChildView::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC paintDC(this);     // device context for painting
    CDoubleBufferDC dc(&paintDC); // device context for painting
    Graphics graphics(dc.m_hDC);    // Create GDI+ graphics context
    mGame.OnDraw(&graphics);
    ...
}
```

Comment: First rule of making performance optimizations: measure your performance where your bottlenecks are happening today.  It might not be where you think.  Posting a [mcve] would be helpful before you take the plunge and re-write with a new renderer.

Comment: I'm pretty confident about where my bottlenecks are because I have timed out different parts of my drawing routine. I posted the function in my code that is currently causing me the most trouble.

Comment: Is your graphics object binded to a memory buffer (in which you blit to the screen after the frame is drawn)?  Or are you drawing directly to the actual Window HDC?

Comment: I'm using a double buffer.  I posted the code on how it's created. I don't believe I'm drawing directly to the window.

Comment: If `Draw` takes up to 20 ms, there is still ~57 ms/frame unaccounted for to make it drop to 13 fps. How long does it take to recreate the `Gdiplus::Graphics` and the related objects every frame? They are probably lightweight but still.

Comment: The other 57ms is from different parts of my drawing routine. I chose to show the part in CTable because it is my biggest bottleneck. If I can figure this out, I can apply the fix to the other areas as well.

Comment: Yeah, you may need to investigate porting your rendering code to DirectX (d2d or d3d).  You may not have a dedicated graphics card, but your Intel CPU does have a GPU worthy of playing 2d games just fine.

Comment: That's disappointing. At least so far, D2D looks much much more difficult to use. Is there any efficient way of porting it other than rewriting it completely?

Comment: This is going to take a ton of time. Is it guaranteed that this will be faster? It will be awful to do this all for nothing.

Comment: It should not take days to build a sample / proof of concept D2D app just to compare with your current GDI+ code, w/o rewriting everything. IMHO, as of today, I would never use GDI nor GDI+ to develop a graphical app (game, etc.) whatsoever.

Comment: @Justin A "Guarantee" can only be left by the implementor - and even then it's a stretch. What **is** known is that GDI++ doesn't use hardware as well as DX. One reasonable approach would be for you to abstract all code dealing with graphics and put it in a layer on top of whatever graph-library you'll use in the end. Porting will become a 1-2 week job instead of a total re-write.

Comment: I would like to thank all of you a ton for all your suggestions. I'm already nearly caught up to where I was and the performance is beyond what I ever imagined. I owe you all. I ended up using Direct2D and it's amazing.

Answer (score 0):

GDI+ doesn't use the hardware at all, unlike GDI where calls to BitBlt are hardware accelerated. In fact, all GDI calls which return a Boolean are backed by the hardware, at least to some degree.

Having worked extensively with both API's, rewriting your renderer to use Direct2D will definitely give you a large performance boost -- even without a "dedicated" video card I imagine the adapter installed in your system supports Direct3D 11.x, which is all you need.

I'd encourage you to go for it.  You can always swing by here if you get stuck.